# Как проверить, находится ли фигура в фигуре?

Tags: математика, геометрия, javascript

Имеются две сложные фигуры с указанными координатами.

Как проверить находится ли фигура в фигуре?

**http://jsfiddle.net/n5d13o1v/**

*Принцип координат фигур*:

[image]

Comment: Надо, чтобы она полностью была вписана или достаточно знать пересечения областей?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мое решение

**http://jsfiddle.net/n5d13o1v/2/**

Comment: Возможно для вас это не критично, но вот недочет: 

![alt text][1]

  [1]: http://upyourpic.org/images/201405/1hj1pazsvc.png

Comment: Спасибо. Добавлю проверку на пересечение двух отрезков.

Answer (score 1):

1. Построить за счет точек и отрезков (векторов) параметрические уравнения прямых.
2. Для любых двух прямых искать точку пересечения, методы есть в гугле. Также есть учебник Воеводина или Куроша по линейной алгебре.

**Обновление**

Тут еще понадобится операция получения вектора из двух точек, и возможно, придется приводить уравнения к общему виду (ax+by+c=0).

Или вот еще одна форма:   http://www.cleverstudents.ru/line_and_plane/line_passes_through_2_points.html

Все эти уравнения друг к другу приводятся.

Answer (score 1):

Может, проще воспользоваться какой-то библиотекой, которая упрощает как и редактирование холста, так и включает в себя дополнительные методы?

Вот смотрите на примере Fabric.js:

```
var Points1 = [
    {x: 0, y: 42},
    {x: 155, y: 0},
    {x: 155, y: 243},
    {x: 0, y: 256}
];

var Points2 = [
    {x: 0, y: 32},
    {x: 135, y: 0},
    {x: 105, y: 203}
];

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('container');

var polygon = new fabric.Polygon(Points1, {
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    fill: 'purple',
    selectable: true
});

var polygon2 = new fabric.Polygon(Points2, {
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    fill: 'yellow',
    selectable: true
});

canvas.add(polygon, polygon2);

canvas.on({
    'object:moving': onChange,
    'object:scaling': onChange,
    'object:rotating': onChange,
});

function onChange(options) {
    options.target.setCoords();
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
        if (obj === options.target) return;

        var isIntersecting = options.target.intersectsWithObject(obj) ||
            options.target.isContainedWithinObject(obj) ||
            obj.isContainedWithinObject(options.target);

        obj.setOpacity(isIntersecting ? 0.5 : 1);
    });
}
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/2v7W2/36/

Comment: Спасибо, но использовать библиотеку ради одной проверки нет желания. Уже решил этот вопрос сам.

Comment: @Essle было бы интересно взглянуть на ваше решение.